# string s= @"somet"hing" what is wrong about this?

Tags: c#, .net, string, escaping

I expected that there is no something wrong but VS2010 gives error.

string s= @"somet"hing";

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to double-up quotation marks within an `@` string.

```
string s = @"somet""hing";
```

Otherwise how would it know which quotes were escapes and which were the end markers?

Refer to [the MSDN string page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx).

Comment: <root
xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">

<h:table>
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>

<f:table>
  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
  <f:width>80</f:width>
  <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table>

</root>

can u put it all of this into a string ? quotation marks are already doubled in it.

Comment: or give idea how to put it into a string in easy way

Comment: @Freshblood: @"<root xmlns:h=""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"" xmlns:f=""http://www.w3schools.com/furniture""> <h:table> <h:tr> <h:td>Apples</h:td> <h:td>Bananas</h:td> </h:tr> </h:table> <f:table> <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name> <f:width>80</f:width> <f:length>120</f:length> </f:table> </root>"